# attr_accessor of one class returns nil in associated class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr-accessor

I have an apartment class with an attr_accessor called checkin (doesn't need to be saved in DB)

```
class Apartment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :checkin
  attr_accessor :checkin

  has_many :rooms
  has_many :beds through: rooms
end
```

In my controller i'm setting checkin's value

```
def show
  @apartment.update_attributes(checkin: session[:checkin])
end
```

When the page renders i call a method of bed which tries to access `self.room.apartment.checkin`
but i am getting nil value

This method is called by a method in apartment. I've debbuged the call and when i am inside the apartment model the checkin variable has a value. 
Why am I getting nil when calling from bed?
Thanks to all helpers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you were calling it from `bed` - as in `bed.apartment.checkin`?

If that is true, that is your problem: you only set `checkin` on the Apartment instance saved in the instance variable `@apartment`. That one is not identical with the instance you receive through `bed.apartment.checkin`.

Comment: I see.. So I should probably pass it as a parameter from the method in Apartment calling the method in bed. Thanks

Comment: Wait, i'm a bit confused.. It's the same apartment, but it's not the same instance? Don't attr_accessors persist between request?

Comment: No, they don't - that would require persistence. On every request to that `show` controller method above, Rails loads the requested Apartment new from the database and puts it into the `@apartment` instance variable. Everything that is not persisted in the database is lost.